# How do I work with the each function in jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm quite new to JS and writing jQuery plugins so it may be a pretty dumb question but I don't know how to approach.

Let's say I have following Plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.test = function(){

         var container = $('#my-container');
         var totalWidth = 0;

         return container.each(function(){
              // totalWidth += get the width of each element
         });

    };
 }(jQuery));
```

Let's assume that the div `#my-container` holds some images like

```
<div id="my-container">
     <img src="wayne" width="200" />
     <img src="wayne" width="300" />
     <img src="wayne" width="400" />
</div>´
```

How can I now set afterwards (once I've iterated each element) the width of the container to the `totalWidth`? I'm pretty confused by this jQuery chaining. Not the principle of chaining, just how I should continue working with the code just out of the each loop?!

If the question is unclear, please comment so I can maybe get more precise.

Best Regards

Comment: Notice too, you don't need to provide any selectors in the test() function so you can call it on any element, select should be controlled by the callers of test so you can use on any set of parent and child elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you don't need to "hardcode"/set the width of container because your child img elements will define the width dynamically but this question is one of principle as Michael just explained to me.

First, since you added `test` as jQuery function, `this` when first entering test function will be the element you select with jQuery and call test on. The jQuery lib, sets this when test is called because it is a jQuery function extension. `this` is the container jQuery object. So you need to iterate the child elements of container, `this` in the each function will be each img element, get the width attribute value with jQuery `attr` and add each width value to the total. Then return `this`, the container, to continue chaining.

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.test = function () {

            var totalWidth = 0;

            this.children().each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('width')) {
                    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).attr('width'));
                }
            });

            if(totalWidth > 0){
                this.css('width', totalWidth);
            }

            return this; //keep chaining going, SinneR

        };
    }(jQuery));
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#my-container').test().css('padding-top', '10px');//test chaining by adding more css
    });
</script>

<div id="my-container">
    <img src="wayne" width="200" />
    <img src="wayne" width="300" />
    <img src="wayne" width="400" />
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not about gathering the width. That's not the problem. How would you set the width of the container at once. Where would you have to put the `container.css('width',totalWidth); ? Theoretically after the each loop, but that won't work because of the chaining.

Comment: In your sample the chaining is lost, or?

Comment: It's more a principle question. But whats about the chaining I mentioned. Isn't it lost the way you proposed?

Comment: I forgot you will need to parseInt the width attribute values because they are strings when returned from attr.

In regards your chaining question, where are you focusing on "losing chaining"?

Comment: var container = $('#my-container') means you stored the container element wrapped in the jQuery object in var, this is saved and is still parent container even though you do a for each next. So you can use that var container later in the code, like I did and you will know it is still the parent container and not a child element. Var container value does not change because you used chaining on it.

Comment: Ah sorry, in my code I was using `this.each(..)` because I call `$('#my-container').test();` ... my fault - kinda brainlaaged. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: SinneR reminded me that you wanted to keep chaining going, check out the answer now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: You don't want the selector, in this case #my-container in the jQuery function extension, you want to be able to call test() on any element, see my answer using this properly to make test an actual extension method and also continue chaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.test = function(){

         var container = $('#my-container');
         var totalWidth = 0;

         container.each(function(){
              totalWidth += get the width of each element
         });

         container.css('width', totalWidth);

         return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This should work and keep the chaining.